# How to find text within a HTML page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

My code below is attempting to find the text "Hello mate" anywhere on a page, and if it exists then display an alert.

```
var array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'))
      .find(el => el.textContent.includes("Hello mate"));
      if (array){
        alert("hi!")
}
```

It's not giving an error, however no alert is appearing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you run this code? If the code runs before the div has been created(such as in `<header>`) then it won't work.

Comment: Its part of a Chrome Extension, in the content script. In the manifest content scripts are set to run at "document_end".

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });

  var array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div'))
      .find(el => el.textContent.includes("Hello mate"));
      if (array){
        alert("hi!")
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="source_your_file"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

<div>Hello mate</div>

</body>
</html>
```

maybe your missing to add your file jquery on your header or your jquery first need call $(document).ready(function(){} . i have example use jquery, maybe it can help you

Comment: jQuery is irrelevant here.